# Remove justification between title and tools on Ext.panel.Header

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Using ExtJS 5.0, I have a panel with a Header that contains a title and tools.  By default, the header left justifies the title then right justifies the tools, but I want to left justify the tools next to the title.  I have tried floating the tools, but this does not work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `flex` property of title:

```
title: {
    text: 'Title',
    flex: undefined
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/5y2K3/1/

Comment: It's good to note that if used within a Window, the close button is shifted with the rest of the tools.

Comment: All I did to fix the above-mentioned issue is added a `tbfill` as the last item in the tools.